# How to get special char as a parameter from url

Tags: php

I have a url like http://localhost.com/api/authenticateuser?user=demo&pass=demo#123

But when i use `$_GET['pass']` i am only able to get value of `$_GET['pass']` is `"demo"` not `"demo#123"`

is there any way to get parameter value as `"demo#123"`

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You have to urlencode your url, in order to escape special / forbidden chars.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: To elaborate, # is a special character in urls (pointing to an anchor within the page). To use it as a part of a query string, it needs to be encoded, which will look like %23 in the URL, but # in $_GET.

Comment: Firstly, I believe one should use rawurlencode instread of urlencode, as urlencode's way of encoding spaces (as '+') is almost deprecated and is kept only for legacy purposes. Secondly, he won't recieve the url server-side, will he? A '#' symbol indicates a fragment and nothing after it (and including it) is returned to the server. This answer will not work as far as I know.

Comment: @Stephen: encoding spaces as + is part of the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type, which is what HTML uses to transmit form data through query strings and the `POST` message body when no file inputs are present.  This media type is still the default for forms in HTML5; as such, it is **not** deprecated.

Comment: @Stephen urlencoding a # means it is no longer a #, but %23. And it does get sent to the server, where it automatically gets decoded. This answer will definitely work, if the OP is constructing the url on the server.

Comment: `rawurlencode` is for use on things that will be used in the HTTP path.  For example: `http://example.com/file+name.php` is invalid, as HTTP doesn't do form url encoding; `http://example.com/file%20name.php` is correct.  But in query strings, either works: `http://example.com/?this=two+words` is correct, as is `http://example.com/?this=two%20words`

Comment: @Maerlyn I'm not very experienced with PHP, but where exactly? If I navigate to `http://localhost/index.html?Parameter=Bob#The%20Dinosaur`, I cannot find a single PHP-side server variable that has the full URI in it. `$_GET[Parameter]` has the value `Bob` of course, and `$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]` is just `/index.html?Parameter=Bob`. I do admit being wrong about urlencode - I am now feeling rather silly about that one. Thanks for the correction @Bemrose.

Comment: @Stephen if you urlencode that hashmark, it becomes %23, and then it will get sent to the server. You used a literal hashmark instead of it's urlencoded form.

Comment: @Maerlyn But how are you meant to urlencode the URL that is being passed? It's most likely being passed from a form being submitted, so php doesn't get a look in - hence why the Javascript answers below. Unless I'm missing something - all our php processing here at work only begins once we've recieved a request from the web-page.

Comment: @Stephen If he is generating such an url while he's generating the page, our work starts even before the request you meant is being started. If it's passed from a form, nothing to be done, browsers urlencode automatically. If it's via ajax, depending on his code he may need to use the javascript encoding function. The question is a bit underspecified.

Comment: @Maerlyn Well I'll be damned. Today I learn how little I know about website coding. Never even occured to me to think that the browser would urlencode form data automatically XD. So, I suppose the only unavoidable solution is directly typing in that URI, but at that point the solution is assumedly to slap the person who did it...

Answer (score 1):

The part after the # is called the *fragment identifier*, and it is not sent to the server. If you want to send it that way, you need to use [encodeURIComponent](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURIComponent.asp).

Comment: I believe it's officially called the "Fragment Identifier" <http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/intro/intro.html#h-2.1.2>. The "#" character itself is called a hash (in the UK at least).

Comment: Thank you, I've edited my answer. I called it hash since you can access it via `window.location.hash`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure the URL is properly escaped - see [URL Escape Codes](http://www.december.com/html/spec/esccodes.html) for a reference. For example, `#` is supposed to be escaped to `%23`.

There are many ways to do this, including using JavaScript function [encodeURIComponent](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURIComponent.asp) (for dynamically generated links).

Answer (score 0):

Well, i'm working on an AngularJS application which checks if the user is logged on every request.

At certain point app redirects the user to /login controller passing user's current state using the parameter "next".

So i've gotten this URL "http://test.dev/login/?next=/#/foo/bar" and i wanted to get the value of $_GET['next'] but wait... Why the heck is that returning only '/' ?

Well, turned out that i needed to use JavaScript method encodeURIComponent() to generate the URL.

Then this: http://test.dev/login/?next=/#/foo/bar, became this: http://test.dev%2Flogin%2F%3Fnext%3D%2F%23%2Ffoo%2Fbar and PHP was able to handle this just fine.